# I'm trying to convert the below SQL stored procedure to Snowflake. But I couldn't find an alternative for the EXEC statement yet:

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to convert the SQL stored procedure shown here to Snowflake. But I couldn't find an alternative for the `EXEC` statement yet

```
DECLARE @Segment_choose varchar(255) = 'All'
DECLARE @SubSegment_choose varchar(255) = 'All'

DECLARE @BREAK int
SET     @BREAK = 0

WHILE (@BREAK < 5) -- the break is <5 because we have 4 segments/subsegments (listed below)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar (8000)
    DECLARE @Segment varchar(255) = CASE
                                        WHEN @BREAK = 4 THEN 'REPOSITORY'
                                        WHEN @BREAK = 3 THEN 'Region'
                                        WHEN @BREAK = 2 THEN 'Time_on_Book'
                                        WHEN @BREAK = 1 THEN 'Sector'
                                    END

    DECLARE @SubSegment1 varchar(255) = CASE
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 4 THEN 'Region'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 3 THEN 'REPOSITORY'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 2 THEN 'REPOSITORY'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 1 THEN 'REPOSITORY'
                                        END

    DECLARE @SubSegment2 varchar(255) = CASE
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 4 THEN 'Time_on_Book'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 3 THEN 'Time_on_Book'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 2 THEN 'Region'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 1 THEN 'Region'
                                        END 

    DECLARE @SubSegment3 varchar(255) = CASE
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 4 THEN 'Sector'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 3 THEN 'Sector'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 2 THEN 'Sector'
                                            WHEN @BREAK = 1 THEN 'Time_on_Book'
                                        END

    DECLARE @Area varchar(255) = CASE
                                     WHEN @BREAK = 4 THEN 'REPOSITORY'
                                     WHEN @BREAK = 3 THEN 'Region'
                                     WHEN @BREAK = 2 THEN 'Time_on_Book'
                                     WHEN @BREAK = 1 THEN 'Sector'
                                 END

    SET @SQL = '

        ;with CTEA as 
        (
        select distinct  Case_created_date
                ,isnull(BUSINESS_AREA,''All'')                                                                              as BUSINESS_AREA
                ,isnull('+@SEGMENT+',''Overall'')                                                                           as Segment
                ,case when concat(
                                    '+@SUBSEGMENT1+'                                                    
                                   ,'+@SUBSEGMENT2+'                                            
                                   ,'+@SUBSEGMENT3+'                                    
                                  
                                  )  = ''''
                       then ''Overall''
                       else  concat(
                                    '+@SUBSEGMENT1+'                                                    
                                   ,'+@SUBSEGMENT2+'                                            
                                   ,'+@SUBSEGMENT3+'                                    
                                  
                                  ) 
                  end                                                                                                       as SubSegment

                 ,'''+@Area+'''                                                                                             as Area
                 ,count(case when case_modified_date = case_created_date then caseID else null end)                         as Cases_Generated      
                 ,sum(manual_case)                                                                                          as Manual_Case
                 ,sum(model_only)                                                                                           as Model_Case
                 ,sum(rules_only)                                                                                           as Rules_Case
                 ,sum(rules_model)                                                                                          as Both_Case
                 ,avg(case when model_Score <> 0 then model_score else null end)                                            as Model_Score                                                                              
        
                          
        from #BR_Master
        
        
        group by grouping sets
              (
               (Case_created_date)                                  
              ,(Case_created_date,BUSINESS_AREA,'+@SEGMENT+') 
              ,(Case_created_date,BUSINESS_AREA,'+@SEGMENT+',REPOSITORY)
              ,(Case_created_date,BUSINESS_AREA,'+@SEGMENT+',Region)
              ,(Case_created_date,BUSINESS_AREA,'+@SEGMENT+',Time_on_Book)
              ,(Case_created_date,BUSINESS_AREA,'+@SEGMENT+',Sector)
              ,(Case_created_date,'+@SEGMENT+')
              ,(Case_created_date,'+@SEGMENT+',REPOSITORY)
              ,(Case_created_date,'+@SEGMENT+',Region)
              ,(Case_created_date,'+@SEGMENT+',Time_on_Book)
              ,(Case_created_date,'+@SEGMENT+',Sector)
              ,(Case_created_date,BUSINESS_AREA)
              ,(Case_created_date,REPOSITORY)
              ,(Case_created_date,REGION)
              ,(Case_created_date,TIME_ON_BOOK)
              ,(Case_created_date,SECTOR)
              )
        )

        insert into #BR_Template
        (
         Reporting_Month
        ,BUSINESS_AREA
        ,Segment
        ,SubSegment
        ,Area
        ,CasES_GENERATED
        ,manual_case
        ,model_case
        ,rules_case
        ,both_case
        ,model_score
        )
        
        select   Case_created_date
                ,BUSINESS_AREA
                ,Segment
                ,SubSegment
                ,Area
                ,CasES_GENERATED
                ,manual_case
                ,model_case
                ,rules_case
                ,both_case
                ,model_score
        
    
        FROM    CTEA 
                                                                         
        
        '

    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @BREAK = @BREAK + 1
END
```

Comment: From  which dbms are you coming? (The above code is product specific. Can perhaps be MS SQL Server?)

Comment: yes MS sql server

Answer (score 0):

A typical stored procedure contains code similar to the following pseudo-code:

```
var my_sql_command1 = "delete from history_table where event_year < 2016";
var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement(my_sql_command1);
statement1.execute();

var my_sql_command2 = "delete from log_table where event_year < 2016";
var statement2 = snowflake.createStatement(my_sql_command2);
statement2.execute();
```

Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#stored-procedure-ddl

Answer (score 0):

An advantage of JavaScript over T-SQL procedural code is JavaScript's encouragement of modularity. Since there's not an built-in match for EXEC, you can write your own function to approximate it as closely as Snowflake differences permit. Here is how to do that:

```
create or replace procedure EXEC_SAMPLE()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    
var out = "";
    
var tableName = "MY_TABLE";
var columnName = "MY_COLUMN";
    
// Note the use of backticks and ${myVariable} replacement usage
var mySQL = `create or replace table ${tableName} (${columnName} string);`;     
    
exec(mySQL);    // Run the "exec" helper function this way if you're not interested in the return results.
    
mySQL = `select * from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."NATION";`;
    
// Run exec this way, assigning to a variable holding the result set if you are interest in the results.
var rs = exec(mySQL);
    
while (rs.next()) {
    out += rs.getColumnValue("N_NAME") + ",";
}

return out;

// -------------------- Main function above; helper functions below --------------------

function exec(sql){
    cmd = {sqlText: sql};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    return rs;
}

$$;

call EXEC_SAMPLE();
```